# Merge датафреймов по условию

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Изучаю самостоятельно `python` и дошёл до `pandas` и манипуляции с данными. Придумал себе задачу:

> Используя сгенерированный список сотрудников расчитать:
>
> - Ежемесячные траты на зарплату этим сотрудникам
> - Количество сотрудников, которым была выплачена зарплата в конкретном месяце
>
> с учётом следующих правил:
>
> - Сотрудник начинает работать в компании при достижении 18 лет
> - Сотрудник заканчивает работать в компании при достижении 65 лет
> - Зарплата сотрудника расчитывается пос елудщей формуле: `Зарплата = (Возвраст - 17) * 100$`

Решил я эту задачу следующим образом:

```
import random as rnd
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

# Константы
# Массив полов
GENDERS = ["M", "F"]
# Массив мужских имён
MALE_NAMES = ["Abraham", "Bill", "Clifford", "Daniel", "Eugene",
            "Fist", "George", "Harold", "Ivan", "Jerome",
            "Kyle", "Leroy", "Max", "Nikodim", "Oleg",
            "Peter", "Qassen", "Romul", "Stefan", "Timothy",
            "Umar", "Victor", "Wincent", "Xavier", "Yard",
            "Zorro"]
# Массив женских имён
FEMALE_NAMES = ["Anna", "Barbara", "Claire", "Diana", "Eleonor",
            "Faith", "Ginger", "Helen", "Irina", "Jeena",
            "Katy", "Leen", "Mary", "Nicole", "Oprah",
            "Patricia", "Queen", "Ruth", "Sequence", "Treesha",
            "Ulyana", "Vega", "Wall", "Xenia", "Yeva",
            "Zena"]
# Массив департаментов
DEPARTMENTS = ["Management", "Human resources",
               "Financial", "Information technologies"]
# Стартовая дата рождения
START_DATE = datetime.date(1957, 1, 1)
# Конечная дата рождения
END_DATE = datetime.date(2004, 1, 1)

# Объект Сотрудник
class Employee():
  def __init__(self, gender, start, end):
    # Получаем переданный пол
    self.gender = gender
    
    # Если пол = М, то имя из списка мужских имён
    if self.gender == "M":
      self.first_name = rnd.choice(MALE_NAMES)
    # Иначе имя из списка женских имён
    else:
      self.first_name = rnd.choice(FEMALE_NAMES)

    # Дата рождения = стартовая дата + случайное число дней от разницы между
    # стартовой датой и конечной датой
    self.dob = start + datetime.timedelta(days=rnd.randrange((end - start).days))
    
    # Департамент = Случайный департамент
    self.department = rnd.choice(DEPARTMENTS)

# Создаём массив из 10 случайных сотрудников
employees = []
for i in range(10):
    employees.append(Employee(rnd.choice(GENDERS), START_DATE, END_DATE))

# Создаём из массива сотрудников DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame([h.__dict__ for h in employees])

# Приводим дату рождения к необходимому типу данных
df["dob"] = df["dob"].astype('datetime64[D]')

print("\nДатафрейм 'Сотрудники':")
df.info()

# Генерируем датафрейм строкой на каждый месяц между
# минимальной датой рождения + 18 лет и
# максимальной датой рождения + 65 лет
dates = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start=(df["dob"].min() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=18)).replace(day = 1),
                                   end=(df["dob"].max() + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=65)).replace(day = 1),
                                   freq="M"),
                     columns=["month"])
print("\nДата фрейм 'Периоды выплат'")
dates.info()

# Загружаем полученные датафреёмы в БД SQLite3
with sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite3") as conn:
    df.to_sql("loaded_data", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
    dates.to_sql("dates", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
    
    # загружаем запрос из файла
    sql_query = '''
    with periods as (
    select date(month) as mm
      from dates),
    employees as (
    select ld.first_name,
           date(ld.dob) as dob
      from loaded_data ld)
    select date(p.mm) as mm,
           sum(100 * (p.mm - e.dob - 17)) as month_pay,
           count(1) as employees_count
      from employees e
      left join periods p on e.dob <= p.mm and (p.mm - e.dob) between 18 and 65
     group by p.mm
     order by p.mm
    '''
    
    print("\nСкрипт запроса:")
    print(sql_query)
    
    # выполняем запрос и результат загружаем в новый датафрейм
    result_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, conn)

print("\nРезультирующий датафрейм:")
result_df
```

Вывод скрипта:

```
Датафрейм 'Сотрудники':
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------      --------------  -----         
 0   gender      10 non-null     object        
 1   first_name  10 non-null     object        
 2   dob         10 non-null     datetime64[ns]
 3   department  10 non-null     object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(3)
memory usage: 448.0+ bytes

Дата фрейм 'Периоды выплат'
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1076 entries, 0 to 1075
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   month   1076 non-null   datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
memory usage: 8.5 KB

Скрипт запроса:
with periods as (
select date(month) as mm
  from dates),
employees as (
select ld.first_name,
       date(ld.dob) as dob
  from loaded_data ld)
select date(p.mm) as mm,
       sum(100 * (p.mm - e.dob - 17)) as month_pay,
       count(1) as employees_count
  from employees e
  left join periods p on e.dob <= p.mm and (p.mm - e.dob) between 18 and 65
 group by p.mm
 order by p.mm

Результирующий датафрейм:
mm  month_pay   employees_count
0   1975-01-31  100 1
1   1975-02-28  100 1
2   1975-03-31  100 1
3   1975-04-30  100 1
4   1975-05-31  100 1
... ... ... ...
1071    2064-04-30  4800    1
1072    2064-05-31  4800    1
1073    2064-06-30  4800    1
1074    2064-07-31  4800    1
1075    2064-08-31  4800    1
1076 rows × 3 columns
```

Текущую задачу я решил путём джойна (`left join`) на уровне `sql`-запроса (присутствует в выводе скрипта). Т.е. приходится подключать лишнюю библиотеку `sqlite3`, которая тут нужна только потому что, задачу я решил с помощью `sql`.

Пытался решить эту задачу с помощью `pd.merge()`, однако так и не понял каким образом осуществить `merge` по условию: `А.Поле <= Б.Поле and (Б.Поле - А.Поле) between 18 and 65`?

**UPD**:
Благодаря **@passant** нашёл решение:

```
# Вводим поля для full join
df["key"] = 1
dates["key"] = 1

# Производим full join по полям key и удаляем их после этого
merge = pd.merge(df, dates, on ="key").drop("key", axis=1)

# Отфильтруем необходимые данные (дата рождения меньше месяца 
# оплаты или равна ему) и возраст на момент оплаты между 18 и 65
merge = merge[(merge["dob"] <= merge["month"])
             &((merge["month"] - merge["dob"]) // np.timedelta64(1, "Y")).between(18, 65)]

# Посчитаем зарплату для каждого сотрудника в каждом месяце,
# исходя из его возраста
merge["salary"] = (((merge["month"] - merge["dob"]) // np.timedelta64(1, "Y")) - 17) * 100

# Сгруппируем и просуммируем
result_df = pd.DataFrame(merge.groupby("month").sum("salary"))
result_df
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на замечания к вашему вопросу. Вы привели простыню ненужного кода, но не привели воспроизводимый пример рабочих данных.

Comment: @strawdog, спасибо! Исправлено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вы надеюсь понимаете, генерировать вашу базу данных, что-бы восстановить потом всю последовательность ваших действий вряд-ли кто захочет. Привели бы воспроизводимый фрагмент Датафрейма с данными -  можно было бы написать конкретный ответ. А так -  только пример. Ваша задача решается в два хода:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': [1,22,33,35,49], 'col_b': ["A", "B", "C","D","E"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': [10, 20, 30,40,50], 'col_b': ["A", "B", "C","D","E"]})

df12=df1.merge(df2, on='col_b', suffixes=["A", "B"])
df12[(df12.col_aA<=df12.col_aB)&((df12.col_aB-df12.col_aA).between(3, 7))]
```

Результат:

```
   col_aA col_b  col_aB
3      35     D      40
```

А тюнинговать этот ответ теперь уж вам самому.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но именно поэтому и выложил весь блокнот, чтобы можно было просто запустить его. Каюсь - про загрузку запроса из файла не подумал (файл надо создавать руками), но в свое оправдание скажу, что текст запроса так же приложен в вопрос :-) За ответ спасибо. Сейчас покручу его в голове, и если справлюсь- укажу Ваш ответ как решение.  Ещё раз спасибо!